# Subtract hour using "Singapore Standard Time" timezone

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, timezone, datetime-conversion

```
select (convert(datetime ,SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2022-02-11 11:15:00.000'),
   (select current_utc_offset FROM sys.time_zone_info where name ='Singapore Standard Time')
))) CurrentTime
```

How can I achieve below expected result ?

**Current Result:**

```
CurrentTime
-----------------------
2022-02-11 19:15:00.000
```

**Expecting Result:**

```
CurrentTime
-----------------------
2022-02-11 03:15:00.000
```

**PS:** I can't use `-8` or `-08:00` in the script.

Comment: why can't you use `-8` or `-08:00` in the script? is there any reason?

Comment: `select convert(datetime , cast('2022-02-11 11:15:00.000' as datetime) at time zone 'Singapore Standard Time' at time zone 'utc')
CurrentTime`

Comment: @lptr Works fine. Thanks!

Comment: @D-Shih This is the part of requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offsets in sys.time_zone_info are those to switch from UTC+00:00 to another timezone.

So for "Singapore Standard Time" that's +08:00

But the sign can be changed if it needs to switch to UTC timezone.

```
SELECT (CONVERT(DATETIME, 
           SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-02-11 11:15:00.000'),
             (SELECT TRANSLATE(CURRENT_UTC_OFFSET,'+-','-+') FROM sys.time_zone_info WHERE name ='Singapore Standard Time')
     ))) AS CurrentTime
```

Better is to use the `AT TIME ZONE` syntax :

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(DATETIME, (CONVERT(DATETIME, '2022-02-11 11:15:00.000')
          AT TIME ZONE 'Singapore Standard Time'
          AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')) AS CurrentTime
```

Both methods will return the same :

| CurrentTime |
| --- |
| 2022-02-11 03:15:00.000 |

Comment: Note that while Singapore is currently fixed to UTC+8, there's no guarantee that it always will be.  But also, other time zones change offsets periodically for daylight saving time or changes to standard time.  Thus, the first code sample that looks up the *current* offset and applies it to an arbitrary timestamp should be avoided.  Only the `AT TIME ZONE` approach is correct.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Good point. But `sys.time_zone_info` is a system table. No idea if it's used under-the-hood by the `AT TIME ZONE` syntax. But it wouldn't surprise me that the difference will probably be coherent in the same MS Sql Server version.

Comment: It is the same list, but the table isn't used during conversion.  In that table, the current offset is dynamically projected based on the datetime right *now*.  It is the offset that is *currently* in effect for each time zone.  It is not necessarily the offset that is in effect at the timestamp being converted in that query, so the table should not be joined to directly for conversion purposes.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that the system table should be used only to ensure a time zone id is valid, or to look up the list of time zones.  The current offset in that list is useful for sorting or filtering the list, but not much else.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Thanks for the insights. Hadn't really thought that far about it. The OP probably also gets notified from your comments.